# Ubuntu 15.10 Headphones No Sound

Tags: sound, alsa, intel, 15.10, headphones

I have purchased a laptop: Alienware 17 r2

Installed Ubuntu 15.10 (Kernel 4.2.0-18-generic) and am having issues with getting sound through the audio jack using headphones & external speakers.

```
$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: synapse Kernel: 4.2.0-18-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.2.1) Desktop: Unity (Gtk 3.16.7-0ubuntu3)
           Distro: Ubuntu 15.10 wily
Machine:   System: Alienware product: Alienware 17 R2 v: A06
           Mobo: Alienware model: Alienware 17 R2 v: A00 Bios: Alienware v: A06 date: 07/24/2015
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-4710HQ (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 19986
           clock speeds: max: 3500 MHz 1: 2500 MHz 2: 2500 MHz 3: 2500 MHz 4: 2500 MHz 5: 2796 MHz 6: 3251 MHz
           7: 2500 MHz 8: 2772 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.2 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.02hz, 1366x768@59.79hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.2.0-18-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: alx port: d000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath10k_pci bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1256.3GB (1.7% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST1000LM024_HN size: 1000.2GB temp: 39C
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: LITEONIT_L8T size: 256.1GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 46G used: 5.0G (12%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-2: /home size: 856G used: 298M (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 17.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 61.0C mobo: 27.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 267 Uptime: 40 min Memory: 942.2/15933.4MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.2.1
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.421) inxi: 2.2.16
```

This is the dmesg output:

```
$ dmesg | grep snd
[    8.828181] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.828348] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    8.828369] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.848818] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for CA0132: line_outs=1 (0xb/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.848822] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.848832] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.848834] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.848834] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    8.848836] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x12
[    8.848837] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D0:      Line=0x11
```

And lspci output:

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio" 
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0688
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
        Memory at f751c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0688
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
        Memory at f7518000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
```

alsamixer screenshots:

[alsa-mixer_hda-intel-hdmi.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLXO0.png)

[alsa-mixer_hda-intel-pch.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yT15.png)

I have tried solutions from a countless number of answers to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit**

Output of aplay as requested by [katu txakurra](https://askubuntu.com/users/188999/katu-txakurra):

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Looking at my latop running debian jessie in `pavucontrol` under output devices when I plugin headphones the port dropdown automatically changes to `headphones (plugged in)` and has the options in the dropdown for `speakers` and `headphones`. This is not the same on my ubuntu machine. There is only one option in the `pavucontrol` port dropdown on the output devices tab and it is called `Line Out (plugged in)`. If I plug in headphones nothing changes... Does this mean it is an issue with the ubuntu machine not automatically recognising the headphones being inserted?

Comment: Could you add the output of  `sudo aplay -l`?

Comment: Sure can! Please see the edit in my question.

Comment: Try `speaker-test -t wav -Dplug:front` If the headphones start working, the problem is likely to be that your default card is the HDMI.

Comment: the output of that command is: `Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

Often after the installation of Linux on laptop the audio is recognized but just switched off ("muted"). You must check two possible points.

1. In terminal, run `alsamixer`. Be sure that playback channels for your audio are not 0 or 'M'
2. Install application 'pavucontrol', run it and ensure you audio card is set to output or combined mode and not muted.

Comment: I have checked settings in `pavucontrol` configuration is set to `analog stereo duplex` and nothing is muted. In `alsamixer` I thought `MM` is muted and `00` is open.  I have never had an issue with sound before so this is all new to me... Looking at the `alsa-mixer_hda-intel-pch.png` screenshot does anything look off at all? Should I have a volume slider for `HP/Speaker`? The only real obvious thing for me is that when I go to `HP/Speaker` there is no `[dB gain: 0.00, 0.00]` showing in the item section.

Comment: 00 is zero volume. Press "Up" when the channel is selected. However, many channels can only be toggled - they are switchers, essentially. Did you press F6 ? How many cards are there? 
HP/Speaker is mos likely the stub for internal beeper that is supposed to beep when PC turns on. It is often missing nowdays.

Comment: ok well there is no headphones channel to select so im assuming thats the problem :/